# Parameterized tests for this if statement

Tags: java, junit

```
   public static Grade fromPercentage(int g) throws IllegalArgumentException  {
    if (g >= 79 && g <= 100) {
        return new Grade(1);
    }
    if (g >= 76 && g <= 78) {
        return new Grade(2);
    }
    if (g >= 73 && g <= 75) {
        return new Grade(3);
    }
    if (g == -1) {
        return new Grade(20);
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

How can I write parameterized tests for this `if` statement.

```
@Test
public void frmPerc2() {
    Grade perc2 = Grade.fromPercentage(76);
    assertEquals(perc2, new Grade(2));
}
```

Currently I'm writing this way for junit however assertEquals getting error.

Comment: does Grade implement/override equals? Does `System.out.println(new Grade(2).equals(new Grade(2)));` print out true or false?

Comment: there is no system.ou.println

Comment: I meant you should use that as a test to see if equals would work in theory on your Grade object.

Comment: oh, it says false...it should be true

Comment: then override `equals` method in your `Grade` class

Comment: i can't i'm not allow to change anything in grade class, that y i'm asking if there any other method

Comment: Is there a getter method in the Grade class that returns the "2" Integer/int value? If yes then you could just test on this directly.

Comment: Is your question how to make `assertEquals` work without implementing `equals` (in that case, do something like `assertTrue(equals(grade1, grade2))` and implement `equals(Grade g1, Grade g2)` externally) or how to make a parameterized test? Those are _very_ different questions.

Comment: nope im not using getter

Comment: @XtremeBaumer how can write that method, i never use overrride before

Comment: in case you use `eclipse` as IDE, you can let it generate the method. `ALT+SHIFT+S` and select `Generate hashCode() and equals()`

Comment: @XteremeBaumer Thanks for help, finally fix it :)

Comment: @kaqqao sry for the confusion